# How to use datatable in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatable

I'm using datatable 4 with Codeigniter, but I'm having problems with the buttons of my table: when I click the button it says [error 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gkg7.png).

I don't know why that error appears, because I have the function created and it's in the same controller. This a line of my code:

```
<a href="'.base_url().'computo_controller/darBaja/'.$numSer.'" role="button">
    <i class="fas fa-trash btn btn-light" title="Dar de baja"></i>
</a>
```

and this is my function :

```
function darBaja($numSer){
    $this->db->where('numSerie',$numSer);
    $data = array(
        'Status' => "0"
    );
    $this->db->update('equipo',$data);
    redirect('computo_controller');
}
```

Comment: Dont use `_controller` in your url actual url will be like `base_url().'computo/darBaja/`

Comment: Your controller class name is `computo_controller`?

Comment: I don't think you need to add `.` before `base_url` in `<a>` tag, still can you tell error is pointing to which part?

Comment: Copy the generated HTML for the snippet you showed to your question as out of context there could be hundreds of possibilities. I suspect @VinayPatil is correct that you are calling the incorrect end point but it is impossible to tell if your generated URL is valid in the first place.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie yes your right. In my answer I consider the URL specified in the question in correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think  you  have missed the php tag in the html part. It should be like the below code.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'computo_controller/darBaja/'.$numSer; ?>" role="button">
    <i class="fas fa-trash btn btn-light" title="Dar de baja"></i>
</a>
```